# On an equivalent definition of the derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am following *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh

Pugh says that the statement $$f(x+h) = f(x) +f'(x)h + R(h) \implies \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{R(h)}{|h|} = 0 $$

is equivalent to the definition of derivative 
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

I am having troubles with proving that one implies the other and the backwards direction too (I am not sure how can I pull $h$ out of the limit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's begin with
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x),
$$
which I immediately rewrite as
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) = 0.
$$
What does this actually mean, with the limit? This means that
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) = \epsilon(h)
$$
and $\epsilon(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, and this makes sense for all $h$ in some $\delta$-neighborhood of $0$. We can multiply through by $h$ to get
$$ f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x)h = h\epsilon(h),$$
which can be rewritten as
$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + h\epsilon(h).$$
Here, what I call $h\epsilon(h)$ is what he calls $R(h)$.

This is how you show one direction. The other direction is very similar. $\diamondsuit$